# how to insert indefined jlabel into jscrollpane?

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel, jquery-jscrollpane

I have many Jlabel that must be insert into jscrollpane. How can I do this?
For example:

```
             JScrollPane scrollPane;
            JPanel pan = new JPanel();
       JLabel[] labeltitoli= new JLabel[50];
      pan.setLayout(null);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pan);
    scrollPane.setBounds(653, 32, 179, 145);

     int cont=50;
     int i=0;

      for (i=0; i<cont; i++){
       labeltitoli[i] = new JLabel(" " + i);
    //how can i insert this into Jscrollpane?}
```

but cont it's not definend (
as my JLabel are extracted from my db). Thank's for answers.

Comment: Try `scrollPane.add(labeltitoli[i])` ?

Comment: `pan.setLayout(null)` would be my first concern

Comment: "Normally", you'd use `pan.add(...)`

Comment: @jr593 You never want to use `add` on a `JScrollPane`, a scroll pane has a `JViewport` which contains the "view" which is actually displayed, so you want to add components to the view :P

Comment: *"but cont it's not definend ( as my JLabel are extracted from my db)"* doesn't effect the answer, you have a list of values which which need to be added to your scroll pane, you use `pan.add(...)`, how you make the "list of things" is up to you, for example, if it's coming from your db, then maybe you could do it as you parse the `ResultSet`

Comment: using resulset and pan.add (.. ) I see no All JLabel but only ones Those Falling in my panel . Also I do not see the scroolbar

Comment: if i dont use pan.setLayout(null) it work but not in vertical, only in orizontal.. I use  `labeltitoli[cont].setBounds(0, 10 + y, 138, 29);` where y increment +20 in for (for is only an exemple, i use while(resultset.next())

Comment: @MadProgrammer 
how can come next line with jlabel? i dont want see that all on 1 line

Comment: The JScrollPane use the preferredSize of the panel to determine when to show scroll bars, thus information is typically calculated by the layout manager ... Which you've discarded

Comment: i resolve it with BoxLayout but now, how can i decide dimension of jlabel? .setBounds dont work

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Fair comment

Comment: You don't, you let the layout managers to their jobs. You can use things like EmptyBorders and, if the layout provides it, other constraints to effect how the component is laid out